# Are there any differences between AVFoundation and AudioToolbox in performance in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation, audiotoolbox

I want to use these Framework to play sound in my iOS app.  Can you advise the  pros and cons of AVFoundation or AudioToolbox?

Comment: Even the framework names imply the difference. One is audio-visual (AV) the other one is audio dedicated. But I think your question is a bit too vague, please specify what your intention is.

Comment: I tried to make it clear

Answer (score 2):

You would have to read about the frameworks and see which one is suitable for your use-case.

You should start with this: https://developer.apple.com/audio/

These frameworks are not substitute to each other. They are built for covering various levels of interaction.

For example, if your use-case is covered by using AVPlayer or Media Player then you do not need to use other framework. In case, you need something more out of the system u may consider other lower level frameworks.